# Доступ к разделяемому ресурсу самым наивным образом

Tags: синхронизация, процесс, распараллеливание, прерывания

Пусть имеется 2 процесса, имеющие доступ к одному и тому же ресурсу.

Поступаем самым примитивным способом:

запрещаем все прерывания

{

```
         вход в процесс 1
    процесс
   разрешение на прерывание
```

}

запрещаем все прерывания

{

```
         вход в процесс 2
    процесс
   разрешение на прерывание
```

}

Понятное дело, что это далеко не лучшее решение для синхронизации двух процессов, так как если один процесс зациклился, то второй никогда не выполнится. Второе, один из процессов во время невыполнения будет всегда находится в режиме активного ожидания. Третье, мы просто параллельные процессы сделали последовательными.

У меня возник вопрос: далее после описания метода сказано, что 2 процесса могут оказаться в критической секции одновременно. Я не вижу такого расклада, как он может возникнуть?

Comment: Имеется в виду какая-нибудь embedded-система? Современные ОС не дают юзермодовскому коду запрещать прерывания.

Comment: Здесь, скорее, это рассматривается теоретически..

Comment: Ну, раз теоретически, то непонятно, что имеется в виду под критической секцией в точности.